# dataSize({}) for mongodb mongomapper and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

im trying to get the size of a single collection, fs.chunks, but cant seem to run the command successfully.

in console, this is what I need:

```
    db.fs.chunks.dataSize({})
```

in Rails im trying stuff like:

```
    = MongoMapper.database.collection('fs.chunks').dataSize({})
    = MongoMapper.database.collection('fs.chunks').runCommand('dataSize({})')
```

any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `MongoMapper.database.collection('fs.chunks').stats` give you the information you want?

```
{
  "ns"             => "app-test.fs.chunks",
  "count"          => 6,
  "size"           => 4160,
  "avgObjSize"     => 693.333333333333,
  "storageSize"    => 8192,
  "numExtents"     => 1,
  "nindexes"       => 1,
  "lastExtentSize" => 8192,
  "paddingFactor"  => 1.58,
  "flags"          => 1,
  "totalIndexSize" => 8192,
  "indexSizes"     => { "_id_" => 8192 },
  "ok"             => 1.0
}
```